# I can't see map after adding google map sdk for ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to add a google map above a UIViewController. But I can't see anything except some markers I defined. The problem looks like this:
[image]
And here is the related code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
previousContext = [EAGLContext currentContext];
[super viewDidLoad];


GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                        longitude:151.2086
                                                             zoom:10];

mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1136, 640) camera:camera];
//mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
mapView_.delegate = self;
// Listen to the myLocation property of GMSMapView.
[mapView_ addObserver:self
           forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
              options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
              context:NULL];

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext: previousContext];

//add makers
CLLocationCoordinate2D position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.900285, 116.274020);
GMSMarker *marker = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position];
marker.title = @"aaa";
marker.snippet = @"population : 5";
marker.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
marker.map = mapView_;
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tempmarker.png"];

CLLocationCoordinate2D position2 = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(39.860285, 116.274020);
GMSMarker *marker2 = [GMSMarker markerWithPosition:position2];
marker2.title = @"bbb";
marker2.snippet = @"population : 5";
marker2.infoWindowAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
marker2.map = mapView_;
marker2.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tempmarker2.png"];



//add buttons:directRoom, rank, achievement, mission, home
....

[self.view insertSubview: mapView_ atIndex: 0];

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
// Ask for My Location data after the map has already been added to the UI.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
});
}
```

So, how to deal with this problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For reference, see the demo from Google (copied below). It's similar to what you posted, but you can try a couple of things:

1. make sure your API key is valid and the API can fetch tiles
2. check the z-index ordering of the map view you're inserting: `[self.view insertSubview: mapView_ atIndex: 0];` inserts behind everything else. Try `[self.view addSubview:mapView_]`

Demo code, from Google (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/):

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import "DemoViewController.h"

@implementation DemoViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.868
                                                          longitude:151.2086
                                                               zoom:6];
  GMSMapView *mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

  GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
  marker.position = camera.target;
  marker.snippet = @"Hello World";
  marker.animated = YES;

  self.view = mapView;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have entered the google API key correctly in the didFinishLaunchingWithOption in your app delegate

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"yourGoogleAssignedSDKKeyGoesHere"];
```

And your xcode should be 4.5 or later